# Looking for a phrase/word similar to cross-department?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, sentence

Let's say a company has a few different locations/branches (e.g. one in New York, one in D.C.). 
I'd like to ask:

> ... are there any cross-site activities or meetups for teams based in
>   New York and teams based in D.C.?

But can I use "cross-site" here? I coined the phrase myself by borrowing the same idea in *cross-department,* which is commonly used.

---

If there are better ways to express what I tried to say by completely restructuring the sentence, please also let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix inter- is appropriate for activities between or among units, e.g., departments or nations or, in you case, sites.

https://www.dictionary.com/e/inter-vs-intra/

> Inter- is a common prefix that means between or among groups. For example, the interstate highway is a road system that goes between states, connecting them together. Similarly, the word international means between or among nations. The internet is referred to as such because it’s a network that connects people and content from all around the world. It isn’t restricted to a particular country or group of people.